# AWS Origin(IP) of incoming requests

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to implement a basic onion routing service on Amazon EC2.
The basic concept behind my network is as follows: I have a directory node, chain nodes, and an originator (the client). The chain nodes register with the directory node, which in turn determines the routes for the traffic.

Everything runs fine, when I run it locally on my machine. When I run every component from an individual EC2 instances, it does not work. This is because the directory node doesn't see the "real" location of the chain nodes, so when they register with it, it thinks they have other IPs. I noticed this behavior when registering chain nodes that were running on my machine, with a directory node running on an EC2 instance. The directory node saw the register requests as coming from within the amazon network. The way the nodes are communicating with each other is through REST. The directory node gets the address of the chain nodes from the request header, which seems to always point to somewhere within the AWS network, instead of pointing to the true origin of the request.

I am new to cloud computing and this is my first interaction with AWS.To the best of my ability I couldn't find an answer for my problem online, so I decided to ask here. Perhaps it is worth mentioning that I did read about Elastic IPs, but as far as I understand it, they are a kind of "static" IP used to reach the instances. This would not help me as the chain nodes should eventually be generated dynamically each in it's own VM depending on the number of nodes alive. In this case, the directory node would not know the IP of the new chain nodes, be it Elastic or not.

Do you have any advice for me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you use the IP in the request header to communicate?

Comment: Because of the following scenario: Directory node is on EC2. Chain node is on my PC and tries to register. The directory node sees the following: Register request received from: <Amazon DNS> instead of <IP of my local machine>. Then when it tries to tell that node that it has to route a piece of traffic, it attempts to talk to the <Amazon DNS> and the chain node has no idea it has to do anything, as it is located at <IP of my local machine>.

Comment: How does the software on your PC reach the directory node on EC2?  What is your network configuration?

Comment: It uses the public DNS of the directory node. The DNS is hardcoded in a properties file. I am attempting to do this for learning purposes, so I'm assuming the location of the directory node would always be known, so that the chain nodes and the client can talk to it. Is it possible that the traffic gets routed through proxies within the AWS network before reaching my EC2 instance? And if so, what would be an appropriate way to let the directory node know the real location of the chain nodes?

Comment: On your EC2 instances, run two commands -- `ec2metadata --public-ipv4` and `ec2metadata --local-ipv4`.  Does one of the two different addresses for each instance match the unexpected address you are seeing?  If so, I can explain...

Answer (score 0):

There are no proxies inline with AWS traffic unless you create one yourself (e.g. with an Elastic Load Balancer).

I suspect the confusion is explaibed as follows.

Every instance with a public IP address in EC2 has an automatic DNS hostname.  For example, if you have an instance in the us-west-2 region, with public IP address 203.0.113.254, that machine would also have a hostname similar to this:

```
ec2-203-0-113-254.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Outside of AWS, this hostname works as expected.

Within one VPC, it's different.

All EC2 instances have private IP addresses. If the instance *also* has a public address, it won't directly know about it.  The public IP is translated to the private IP by the VPC Internet Gateway.

When one instance inside a VPC accesses another instance inside the VPC *using a hostname like the one shown above*, VPC's internal DNS resolver will, by default on your default VPC for each region, return the *private* IP of the destination instance, not the public IP.  Thus the target machine will see the *private* IP of the client, not the public IP.

This is useful because machines inside a VPC incur additonal data transport charges when talking to other instances inside the VPC using their public IP addresses, but the additional charge is not applicable when using private IPs.

If you use a different hostname, not the one provided by AWS, to access the instance, this remapping does not occur.  For example...

```
my-chain-node-zero.203.0.113.254.xip.io
```

...would also resolve to 203.0.113.254 but would not exhibit this remapping behavior.  (Read how http://xip.io works.  I am not affiliated with the provider of that service.)

Or if you have your own domain, create `A` records pointing to the public IP addresses in question.  Do not create `CNAME`s referencing the Amazon-provided hostnames -- those *will* remap when the `CNAME` chain is followed.

See also [Using DNS with your VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However it is still not clear to me how I could use xip.io to get the real IP of the chain nodes. The only known address is the one of the directory node. Then the chain nodes make requests to it and the directory node has to find out and store their locations. As I understand it from your answer, the directory node would then see the private IP of the chain nodes instead of the public one. Can xip.io be used without knowing the location of the node making the request (in this case the chain nodes)?

Comment: Or did you mean I should use xip.io to access the directory node? Something like my-directory-node.203.0.113.254.xip.io instead of my-chain-node-zero.203.0.113.254.xip.io ?

Comment: Since you didn't privide specific examples in the question, I assumed your nodes were connecing to other nodes using their ec2 hostnames.  The idea here is not using this in a reverse direction but in the forward direction.  You may want to provide specific examples of what connects to what, and how (by name or by IP), and the actual vs expected results.  See my comment on the question, regarding ec2metadata.